# Deletion of version of a Document when Version Label is known using powershell script

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, script

Is it possible that I can delete versions of a particular document when I have a pool of minor Versions available? 
NB: I do not want to iterate through all the item versions, but just access through the Version Label and delete them.

Answer (score 0):

Several [methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj246282.aspx) allow you to retrieve the specific version by its ID or label and since you are about to delete them, I think `DeleteByLabel()` is the most appropriate:

[file.Versions.GetById()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/jj245025.aspx)

[file.Versions.deleteByID()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/jj246024.aspx)

[file.Versions.DeleteByLabel()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj245698.aspx)

For Powershell:

```
$file.Versions.DeleteByLabel($Label)
```

Comment: Thank You! DeleteByLabel() method will be of great help!